# Javascript form submits even when variable is false

Tags: javascript, forms

So I am trying to have the user confirm their action before they submit the form, so I tried using the confirm box.  When I tested it, even when I pressed Cancel in the confirm box the form submitted.  So I tried just setting variable 'c' to false and then saying if c==true, submit the form, and the form still submitted!  I don't understand why this is happening.  Any help would be appreciated!

**So just to be clear, the form still submits in the following code:**

```
<button onclick=\"extendBids('$studentID')\">Extend Bid</button>
    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"extendBid\" id=\"$studentID 2\" value=\"$studentID\" style=\"visibility: hidden\"></input>


function extendBids(studentID) {
   document.getElementById(studentID+" 2").checked=true;
   //var c=confirm("Are you sure? This action cannot be undone.");
    var c=false;
    if (c==true){
      document.forms["addToRush"].submit();
   }
}
```

Comment: The code snippet, as given, works.  Any chance of there being a line farther down -- unseen here -- that triggers submit?  Or is this code called in a handler for a `input type='button'` that could cause the form to submit.

Comment: ok i gave some more information about where it is being called from

Comment: Dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms

Comment: @garethb called it.  Seeing the context this is a known issue. Check out the post he linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
<button onclick=\"extendBids('$studentID');\">Extend Bid</button>
    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"extendBid\" id=\"$studentID 2\" value=\"$studentID\" style=\"visibility: hidden\"></input>


function extendBids(studentID) {
   document.getElementById(studentID+" 2").checked=true;
   if(confirm("Are you sure? This action cannot be undone.")){
      document.forms["addToRush"].submit();
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```